# pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip

Tags: pdftex, color, pdfcomment, fancytooltips, tooltips

I work as a Physics teacher and I am writing a "Problem-Solution-Book" with 
hyperlinks from problems to solutions and backreferencing -- all of it works pretty good.

Now I wanted to introduce something like a "Hint" - text at the problem header which is used as a tooltip, indicating some hints for possible ways to the solution (apart from directly clicking the "solution" link ;-))

I wonder whether it is possible to use `LaTeX` code in the second argument of
the `\pdftooltip` command from `pdfcomment` package by Josef Kleber. I am using `pdflatex` and `pdfcomment` version 2.3a.

What I want to do is:

Using the `\pdftooltip` command and as the mouse moves over the relevant portion a tooltip box with, say, blue background colour, appears.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\pdftooltip{foo}{%
\colorbox{blue}{%
Hint: What is the definition of foo?}% End of Colorbox
}% End of pdftooltip command

\end{document}
```

(Well it compiles without complaining, but it does not give the expected result :-( )

However, there is no blue background colour but an almost verbatim 
text of `colorbox` ... blue etc., bracketed by (presumably) pdf code.

I know, that there is the possibility of mathematical markup in `pdftooltips`, but what about "eye candy"? ;-)

Edited: I know of the packages `fancytooltips` or `cooltooltips` but they do not match my intents

Comment: Something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108998 ?

Comment: @AlexG: Thanks a lot for that link, but I've already seen that thread.                                                     Dragging around the tooltip box is not necessary, apart from the security issues by using **fancytooltips** and its insertion of javascript code into Adobe Reader. I also want to have the tooltip statement also in my problem environment and not in a separate external file, as required by **fancytooltips** (or have I misunderstood some options/features of that package?)

Comment: What you see in the answer I linked does not use `fancytooltips`. The tooltip is inserted inline, no external file as requested. Moving the tooltip around is just a bonus feature (The tip text could be wider than the page).

Comment: As for JavaScript, no risk no fun ;).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> ```
> \tooltip[black]{foo}[blue!50]{Hint: What is the definition of foo?}
> ```

If the mouse is moved over 'foo' the tip is shown and it disappears immediately when the mouse is moved out.

In order to drag the tip around, 'foo' must be clicked. The tip remains visible. Move the mouse over the tip, click it and move it around. Click the tip once more to pin it down at the current position.

To hide the tip, wipe over 'foo' with the mouse.

Link text and tip text colours are optional. Besides `pdftex`, all common drivers (`xetex`, `dvips`, ...) are supported.

It is recommended that `<tip text>` is not wider than `\linewidth`, `<tiptext>` should be put into a `\parbox` if necessary.

(Code by M. Scharrer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17808 is used to compute initial left-shift for wider tip text boxes.)

[image]

```
%\documentclass[a6paper,12pt]{scrbook}
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2017/11/28
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]][<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%               
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%              
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}m%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%  
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%  
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\tooltip[black]{foo}[blue!50]{Hint: What is the definition of foo?}

with non-draggable tooltip: \tooltip**[black]{bar}[blue!50]{Hint: What is the definition of bar?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works well. But, shouldn't the tool tip go away upon mouse moving away? This requires a mouse over to toggle it on, and another mouse over to toggle it off.

Comment: @Peter: I tried hard to implement this, but if one tries to relocate the tip box (the bonus feature), the mouse inevitably leaves the link area and the tip would be hidden.

Comment: @AlexG: I seem to have missed the point in that link, that **fancytooltips** is just mentioned but not used at all in that example.  Regarding your code: I will give a try, although it makes use of XeTeX. Thanks

Comment: @Christian: It doesn't make use of XeTeX if you don't want it to be used. The code is just able to cope with any tool-chain, be it `pdflatex`, `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`, `lualatex`, ..., and `xelatex`.

Comment: @AlexG: You are right, Alex... However, the code fails to compile, but I suspect, my TexLive 2010 distribution is to old and it misses some new features such as LaTeX3 extensions. Perhaps, I should update to a newer release before starting manually adding some packages each time my old pdflatex distribution complains about missing or incompatible packages... ;-)

Comment: @AlexG: Moving the mouse away is not sufficient to get the tool tip to go away. You have to move the mouse away, and then move it back to get it to go away.

Comment: @Peter Yes, this is necessary to make the tip draggable. If I had coded it such that the tip goes away when the mouse is moved away, I couldn't move the mouse over the tip to drag it around. The tip would disappear before I could click on it for dragging.

Comment: @AlexG: You should document that behavior in the asnwer as it was not obvious to me.

Comment: @Peter: I could improve the code to make the tooltip work as expected/requested.

Comment: @Christian: Updating TeXLive is a good idea. TeXLive-2013 is out for 3 days now.

Comment: @AlexG: I will test your suggested solution on my notebook and update TeXlive on my workstation as soon as possible ;-) Unfortunately, I have a rather outdated Linux distribution as well, so I should better update the OS too.

Comment: @AlexG: I have switched to TeXLive-2012 as an intermediate state and tried to compile your solution code. However, it fails, stating that \tpPdfLink is an unknown control sequence, stopping at the same position as in old TeXLive-2010...

Comment: @AlexG: TeXLive-2013 does the job ;-) Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexG: Great, thanks. The version http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/latex/tooltip2.tex ensures, that the tooltips appears inside the page bounds. This solves  the problems if the word which activates the tooltip is closee to the right margin. Feel free to use this improvement, if you like it. (For simplicity, the file from my link depends on insdljs.sty, but this dependence can be removed surely)

Comment: Can you please post a solution without clicking and dragging? I do not need such a feature and it makes Foxit Reader crashing. The mouseover works like expected. thx a lot for that

Comment: @Megachip. Done.

Comment: @AlexG I can't get this code to work anymore ? The code is processed as normally but the resulting document has no tooltips. I have JS enabled.

Comment: @1010011010: No problem here with (frozen) TL-13.

Comment: @AlexG Just found this interesting code, but didn't compile at all until I added package `tikz`. Ok... now it hangs with `./tooltip.tex:109: Undefined control sequence.
\tpPdfLastXform ->\g_mix_pdflastxform_tl`. Unfortunately I don't know how to remedy that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, the fixed the code will compile and work again, hopefully.

Comment: I cannot compile this code, currently using pdflatex.

Comment: @Peter No problem here with up-to-date TeXLive. Which error do you get?

Comment: After another update it works perfect, on MiKTeX, sorry for this warning of noncompilalble code...

Comment: I had the same problem as Peter's and had the same solution : update MikTeX.

Comment: A question : is there a mean to copy the comment (or the text with its comment) on another pdf, especially a non Latex pdf, a scanned pdf. An example of this could be the pdfcomments that get easily copied from the Latex pdf to a scanned pdf.

Comment: Is there a hope that someday, the different versions of this macro works with Evince?