# How to have a simple text appearing when the cursor is hovering over a part of the document?

Tags: fancytooltips

I'm trying to get a short description of a picture to appear when the cursor is hovering over this picture in the pdf file. I read that this might be possible using `fancytooltips` but I have to say that after reading through the documentation and some "basic" example, I am not convinced. Could someone explain to me how to modify the following code to get "this is the description" appearing next to the cursor, when this one is above the picture (Is it the same process for another kind of element, ie. pop-up above a word or a paragraph)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example}

\end{document}
```

What are the options I have to customize this pop-up window (shape, background color, persistence, etc.) ?

Comment: I think without the tools provided by `fancytooltips` you simply can not.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino OK. Do you have an idea then how to do it with `fancytooltips`?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: `fancytooltips` is not required. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005

Comment: @AlexG: just upvoted: very nice suggestion, I wasn't aware of that answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `\tooltip` macro defined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005.

```
\tooltip{\includegraphics{example}}[green!20]{this is the description}
```

It works with all common drivers (`pdflatex`, `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`, `xelatex`, ...). Moreover, the pop-up is draggable.

The box background colour of the pop-up box as well as the text colour of the link can be set by optional args. Of course, since the link is an included graphic here, changing the link text colour has no effect.

**NOTE:** This solution requires to have an updated system (TeXLive-2013 or other) and to use `AdobeReader`. For sure it won't work with `Evince` reader.

Comment: That seems to be really promising for my purpose, but when using your macro (the part between the %% lines in the link you have provided) and just inserting your line (`tooltip{...}`) in my MWE, I got an error concerning an undefined control sequence \tooltip. #1#2#3#4 etc. The output pdf is a white page with some writings on it. Apparently it is the `\tpPdfLink` command which is not working. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @LudovicC. Which TeX system do you use? Package `media9` may need to be installed first. I recommend TeXLive-2013. But MiKTeX-2.9 with sync'ed database and updated packages should do as well.

Comment: Okay I am currently running TeXLive-2012 and I am trying to upgrade to TeXLive-2013... Will I need to install the `media9` package with TeXLive-2013?

Comment: @LudovicC. You could try to install media9 in TeXLive-2012 via `tlmgr`, `l3kernel` and `l3packages` may need to be updated too. But an upgrade to TeXLive-2013 is definitely better, as TL-2012 is frozen.

Comment: I have now TeXLive-2013 and the `media9` package and the file compiles properly. However on the output there is no box appearing when the cursor hovers over the picture. Is it possible that the problem comes from my pdf reader (Evince under Ubuntu)? Or is Evince supported by your macro?

Comment: @LudovicC. You need AdobeReader. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

While not as fancy as the tooltip in the answer from @AlexG, you can have contents appear on mouse over/click events using ocg-p:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{ocg-p}

\begin{document}

\toggleocgs[triggerocg=allactions]{1}{%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example}%
}%
\begin{ocg}[listintoolbar=never,printocg=never,exportocg=never]{tooltip}{1}{0}
This is a tooltip
\end{ocg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using PDF layers for this purpose is a nice option. Do you know of a PDF reader other than Adobe Reader, preferably open-source, which would correctly display this example? I tried evince-2.32.0 but it didn't work out. Maybe it is too old version?

Comment: @AlexG: I don't know of any readers apart from Adobe Reader XI that displays you example or mine correctly. I have tried PDF XChangeViewer 2.0 and SumatraPDF 2.3.2 as well as the pdf-viewer build into Chrome.