# How can I make a hyperlink underlined only when the cursor is hovering over it?

Tags: hyperref, moderncv

I'm using the [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) document class along with the [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package, and I have some hyperlinks in my document. I've made my hyperlinks a different color, to ensure that the reader knows they are clickable, but I'd also like to have the hyperlinks underlined whenever the cursor is hovering over them. Is this possible?

Comment: interactivity in pdf tends to limit the readers (often just works with acrobat) but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122444/how-to-have-a-simple-text-appearing-when-the-cursor-is-hovering-over-a-part-of-t

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see (and keepeing in mind that there are several PDF viewer available):

**No, at last it is not possible.**

Reasons:

- Showing effects when one is hovering with the cursor/mouse over a text is not done by all PDF viewers.  So you can't be sure if the document reader will see it because you do not know which PDF viewer  the reader uses.
- The solutions I know (see this side, see the link David gave) shows only more text, but do not underline the existing text in the document.

Perhaps later, if all PDF viewer can handle things like `tooltip` it will be possible with LaTeX.