# How to make abstracts of references in the bibliography to appear in output PDF

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, lyx, biber

I would like to be able to have abstracts of references in the bibliography to be shown in output PDF. It used to be a specialized bibtex style to do that, and I could do it within LyX. However, now I am using biblatex with biber (also within LyX) and I cannot make it work anymore.

I have also tried without success the solution given in [How to get abstracts of referenced works as mouseover texts in the generated pdf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122619/how-to-get-abstracts-of-referenced-works-as-mouseover-texts-in-the-generated-pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `biblatex` standard styles (except for `reading`) don't print the `abstract` field, but they have everything needed to print it ready.

Normally it would be enough to just add something like

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\par}%
  \usebibmacro{abstract}%
  \finentry}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\par}%
  \usebibmacro{abstract}%
  \finentry}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with abstract.]

---

With LyX things are only very slightly more difficult. Assuming you already have everything set up for `biblatex`, you need to add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
    \setunit{\finentrypunct\par}%
    \usebibmacro{abstract}%
    \finentry}}
```

to your document preamble (*Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble*). That is to say you need to wrap the code from above in `\AtBeginDocument{...}` to make sure that the code is only executed after `biblatex` is loaded (otherwise you may get errors about unknown commands).

[image: Screenshot showing the previous preamble code in the LyX preamble setting.]

Comment: Great LyX solution