# ogctools in combination with beamer

Tags: beamer, errors, pdf, ocg

I try to use ocgtools in a beamer presentation, which worked for me some time ago.

But now (TeXLive 2013) this seems not wo work anymore. As soon as I include the ocgtool package there are errors like

> ! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph.
>   \@EveryShipout@Hook ...\@cclv \unhbox \@cclv \fi }

Here a minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ocgtools}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\ocgpicture[width=.5\textwidth]{img}
}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to circumvent this errormessages?

Comment: You could try `ocg-p` and `ocgx` packages...

Comment: The `ocgtools` package is not distributed by TeXLive 2013.

Comment: I installed it manually from CTAN as well as acrotex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. The problem was in forgotten `\hss` in an hbox. It seems that some of the packages unboxes this box in TeXlive2013. However, I think that this `\hss` command has been forgotten from previous versions and can be removed safely.

I just issued the [new version](https://bitbucket.org/robert.marik/ocgtools/src/tip/ocgtools.dtx?at=default) and I will upload on CTAN after some more tests in few days.

Note also that the `\tooltip` macro defined in the answer to [pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-from-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip) might fit better in your document.