# Replace ocgtools' ocgpicture with ocgx

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdf, ocg

Since ogctools isn't working for me with TexLive2013, I try to rebuild its command
`\ocgpicture` which shows a picture and by clicking on this it is show in full size. By clicking on the big picture it should hide again.
This is now my problem. The active region which reacts on the click is on every
ocg, so that it hides only the last ocg.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ocgx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ocgpicture}[3][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=#3,status=invisible, name=#3}]
\node at (current page)
   {\hideocg{#3}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{#2}}};  
\end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\showocg{#3}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\ocgpicture[width=2cm]{img1}{img1}
\ocgpicture[width=2cm]{img2}{img2}
\ocgpicture[width=2cm]{img3}{img3}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The macro `\zoombox{}` defined in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12293  does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is not exactly what I want, but it works at least.

Comment: With OCG, active regions are on a single layer (always active). In case of overlapping, only the last reacts.

Comment: According to ocgtools and texlive2013: the issue has been fixed in development version at https://bitbucket.org/robert.marik/ocgtools and should appear on CTAN within few days or weeks.

Comment: @sanskrit_learner did the `ocgtools` package update resolve this problem for you?

Comment: @PaulGessler Yes, the update worked for me. Hence I also marked [link][http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122972/ogctools-in-combination-with-beamer) as solved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated package version.