# Changing/disabling the mouse over/hover text of a hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, urls, links

I am using `hyperref` package to create links in my tex file. To define a link, I do

```
\href{https://www.google.com}{google}
```

When mouse is over the text, the destination, https://www.google.com in this case, appears as a hovering text.

Is there way to define the hovering text or simply get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: See this question and the related answers, it might help. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005/31058

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the pdfviewer, and it is not something that depends on the latex code.
For example, when I open a .pdf file in Document viewer, the default pdf viewer for Ubuntu, I get no visual reaction on mouse hover. The same document, when I open it with firefox, I get hovering text effect on links.