# Forming a "spoiler text" environment in LaTeX (via Javascript?)

Tags: javascript

I've been writing a mathematical text for some time, and seeing as it is the 21st century, I would like this text to be interactive and dynamic, probably in PDF format. The main function that I am looking to implement is a sort of "spoiler text" environment where the user can click a button to reveal content that is otherwise collapsed and unseen. This could be used to hide answers to exercises or proofs for theorems, etc.

I am led to believe that this is possible by using some form of Javascript embedded in LaTeX. Can somebody point me to a reference that would allow me to implement this, or better yet, explain to me how I should design this "spoiler text" environment?

Comment: You can use links to go to another pages and then go back. I use this sometimes in beamer.

Comment: Someting that works quite well in Adobe Products (Reader, Acrobat) and partially in Foxit-Reader, and which allows for LaTeX formatted pop-ups is given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005/1053

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is an ugly hack, but if nothing else works, well, this will work. This is from [The PracTEX Journal, 2006, No. 4, Article revision 2006/11/03, Hypertext capabilities with pdfTEX
by Federico Garcia.](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/garcia1)

```
\pdfannot width w height h depth d { /Subtype /Text
/Contents (htexti)}
```

This is via pdfTEX primitives, so I have no idea what is going on with it. It makes a postit note in the document that you click on to see the text.

Instructions:

> The three dimensions w, h, and d are all LATEX dimensions. But the one
>   that is important is h (the height), because it determines where the
>   note appears in relation to the text baseline. It is also a good idea
>   use a \qquad after it.

Also note: This works fine in Adobe. It doesn't work at all in Sumatra PDF. Well, the note shows up, but you can't click it. So this is a bit risky (So is javascript for that matter, as a lot of PDF readers avoid it for security reasons).

A bit more from the article:

> One thing to have in mind with post-it notes is that their exact
>   behavior (color, size, when it opens, how it closes, etc.) is not very
>   much standardized, and tends to change from version to version of
>   Acrobat Reader. That said, the note can be of a different color if,
>   between the brackets of \pdfannot, /C [r g b] is appended; a title for
>   the note is determined with /T (title), and the note can show up open
>   by default with /Open true.

Well, that is one way. A terrible, terrible way, but it would technically work.

Comment: Thanks, it is nice to know that the capability exists. Your comment about compatibility with PDF readers is also a good point. At least for my own purposes, I use Adobe Acrobat Professional so there shouldn't be any features that I cannot test myself, hopefully. However, I agree with your opinion that this method seems rather adhoc.

Comment: For formatted text, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005