# pdftooltip (from pdfcomment package) with included graphic?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdfcomment

I would like to show structure formulas associated with chemical compounds in tooltips, but have not been able to achieve that easily.
`\includegraphics` appears to be ignored silently, rather its filename argument is displayed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Perhaps consider the [`fancytooltips` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips).

Comment: Perhaps Alex G's solution to this question migth give a hint: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-from-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip

Comment: With the `\tooltip` command given in the answer that is linked in @Christian 's comment anything can be used as a tooltip, e. g. `\tooltip{some graphics}{\includegraphics{example}}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a tooltip to a graphic:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdftooltip{\includegraphics[scale=2]{chemie}}{tooltip}
\end{document}
```

[image: chemical structure formula]

If you want the graphic to be the tooltip, i'm afrais that's not possible. A PDF tooltip is text only!
You may achive something like this by using OCG layers. Take a look at [demo-ocgx.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx/demo-ocgx.pdf)
And use a full scale PDF viewer like AR! ;-)