# Interactive (hoverable) 2D plots in PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf

It seems that [embedding 3D plots in PDFs](/questions/137109) has been around for a few years now ([`misc3d`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/misc3d/index.html), for example, and [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)), as well as interactive features such as [fancy-preview](/questions/15356/) and [*optional content groups*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocgx) (which could probably be hacked to do what I'm about to ask) but it doesn't seem to be the case for more simplistic 2D plots. I would love to embed interactive 2D plots similar to those seen around the interwebs these days where you hover over a point and the actual value is displayed or trend line is highlighted, etc.

Is it possible to do this with LaTeX / Sweave / or whatever?

A few examples in case I'm still not clear:

- [highlighting when hovering](http://projects.flowingdata.com/life-expectancy/)
- [values when hovering](http://ssz.fr/places/?fr#ac%24//)

Comment: About hovering perhaps the solution to this question might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-from-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 10):

Pgfplots is a plotting package for 2d/3d visualization which can display

- values of point coordinates on click
- trend lines via drag-and-drop (including the slopes)
- arbitrary meta data when clicking onto a data point (both 2d/3d)

To activate it for all `pgfplots` figures in your document, simply write

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}
```

in your preamble.

Details, examples, and screenshots can be seen in the pgfplots manual http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf , here is an excerpt:

> ## 5.1 Clickable Plots
>
> ```
> \usepgfplotslibrary{clickable} % LATEX and plain TEX
> \usepgfplotslibrary[clickable] % ConTEXt
> \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.clickable} % LATEX and plain TEX
> \usetikzlibrary[pgfplots.clickable] % ConTEXt
> ```
>
> A library which generates small popups whenever one clicks into a
> plot. The popup displays the coordinate under the mouse pointer,
> supporting the optional snap-to-nearest clickable coords feature with
> customizable displayed information. Furthermore, the library allows to
> display slopes if one holds the mouse pressed and drags it to another
> point in the plot. The library has two purposes: to compute slopes in
> a simple way and to provide related, optional information to single
> data points which are not important enough to be listed in the main
> text (like prototype parameters or other technical things).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I didn't look into `pgfplots` deeply enough to see that clickable plots are possible. While I will go with that if there are no other alternatives, what I would really prefer is _hoverable_ plots…