# Glossaries and pdfcomment - Tooltip on symbols

Tags: glossaries, pdfcomment

I would like to have a tooltip appear, when I hover the mouse over a glossaries symbol, so the entry's description appears in the tooltip. I am using glossaries v4.33 and pdfcomment v2.4. However the tooltip doesn't resolve the \glsdesc-command in the pdf-output. I won't be needing the link in the \glssymbol, since the information would be presented in the tooltip, which should make my question differ from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199084/tooltip-with-glossary-items)

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{glossaries, pdfcomment}
    \setglossarysection{section}
    \newglossaryentry{ex}{name = {Example name}, symbol = {\ensuremath{\mathcal{E}^n}}, description = {a suitable description for the entry}}
    \makenoidxglossaries
    \listfiles
    \begin{document}
        \pdftooltip{\glssymbol{ex}}{\glsdesc{ex}}
        \printnoidxglossary
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you expect from this?

Comment: I would like a suggested solution, so that the full description appears in the tool tip, where my current pdftooltip-command just resolves to 'ex'.

Comment: It's better to use `\glsentrydesc` rather than `\glsdesc` if it needs to be fully expanded.

Comment: Changing \glsdesc to \glsentrydesc worked.

Comment: I'm trying a similar approach, but I'm also using hyperef with a list of symbols. The symbol is thus clickable and shows the list of symbols. However, the tooltip is not shown in the clickable symbol. It may seen redundant to allow both (tooltip and a link to the list of symbols), but it is some kind of safeguard to viewers which may not show the tooltip. Should a ask a new question?