# Is there a way to automate the adding of tooltips for glossary items?

Tags: glossaries, pdfcomment, fancytooltips, tooltips

As per the questions - I have a large glossary, and where I use `\glssymbol{...}` I would like a tool-tip to be automatically added for that symbol instance, i.e., I do not want to have to pre-define each tool-tip entry, where the tool-tip is the name of the glossary entry. Is this possible?

Comment: Loosely related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199084/134144

Comment: Could you please include a short example document in your question that we can use for testing?