# Hyperlinks with mouseover for link to bibliography

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

I know this might be challenging if at all possible... but then this is the right board ;)

When using hyperlinks to the bibliography in a larger thesis-style pdf the default mouseover text which is displayed is the page number, e.g., "Page #27". 
It can be somewhat annoying to move back and forth between text and bibliography a hundred times when actually you just want a quick info which reference is cited at a given position in the text. This really disturbs the flow of reading.

I know there is the possibility to create custom mouseover text, as described, e.g., in [Mouseover with Hyperref Internal Links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200143/mouseover-with-hyperref-internal-links) but do that for 100+ references?... nah, not really :(

Wouldn't it be cool if the mouseover message would display the corresponding reference in the same way it appears in the bibliography, i.e., just show the bib entry.
The same is true for the linked images, chapters, etc where the information could be the caption or header.

So I'm curious if there is a way to achieve that. I myself gave up on the idea and stuck to the "Page #" thing...