# pdftooltip of pdfcomment package doesn't work in landscape mode

Tags: landscape, pdfcomment, tooltips

I try to use the `\pdftooltip{}` of the pdfcomment package in a document in landscape mode. The mouseover works in normal mode, but fails in landscape mode. In landscape mode onley the first character does a mouseover instead of the whole word. I render the pdf with this rmarkdown script (the first page has a normal tooltip, the second has a wrong one):

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: no
    keep_tex: true
mainfont: Open Sans
header-includes:
- \usepackage{grid-system}
- \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \geometry{top=0.2cm,margin=0.2cm}
- \usepackage{atbegshi}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
- \usepackage{pdfcomment}
---

\pdftooltip{\mbox{mouseover1}}{this is a mouseover text}
\begin{landscape}
\pdftooltip{\mbox{mouseover2}}{this is a mouseover text}
\end{landscape}
```

This is LaTeX file it makes before rendering the pdf:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
    \setmainfont[]{Open Sans}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true,
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

%%% Use protect on footnotes to avoid problems with footnotes in titles
\let\rmarkdownfootnote\footnote%
\def\footnote{\protect\rmarkdownfootnote}

%%% Change title format to be more compact
\usepackage{titling}

% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}}
  \posttitle{}
  \author{}
  \preauthor{}\postauthor{}
  \date{}
  \predate{}\postdate{}

\usepackage{grid-system}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.2cm,margin=0.2cm}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\pdftooltip{\mbox{mouseover1}}{this is a mouseover text}

\begin{landscape}
\pdftooltip{\mbox{mouseover2}}{this is a mouseover text}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? Is there a solution for making pdftooltip work in landscape mode?

*EDIT* Thanks to the comments I sort of understand what happens. The `\pdftooltip{}` doesn't seem to rotate to landscape mode. How can we solve this?

Comment: I can only guess, as my PDF viewer doesn't display tooltips and I'm not gonna install adobe on my machine. But I wonder whether the tooltip does show up if you place your cursor vertically beneath the first character of the landscape word. If so that would be funny/interesting.

Comment: @Skillmon yes that happens!! so the pdftooltip doesn't inherit the landscape mode...

Comment: Rotating annotations is difficult. You can find a number of questions about it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you think this could help: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rotations

Comment: I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415756/121799) may be related. (I'm not saying the question is a duplicate!)

Comment: @marmot I am not quite sure it will help me (mainly because of my lack of LaTeX knowledge), but I will study it. Thanks!

Comment: I think no one but @AlexG could help you here ;-)

Comment: The more I dig into LaTeX the more I stumble upon @AlexG :-)

Comment: @marmot, maybe I can add a rotatebox next to the mbox with phantom words/letters with same length as the mbox content and rotate it back to landscape mode. Haven't tried it yet. Just a reminder, I Will try as soon I am back at my laptop. (Maybe this will be too simple thinking though. ..)