# Spoilers in Web-Accessible Pdf Documents?

Tags: math-mode, macros, environments, amsmath

A highly regarded professor of mine is currently writing a graduate mathematics textbook in which he has given the book a theme of ``do it yourself'' mathematics.

He has asked me to review the book in its early drafts, and one thing I've noticed is that some one the theorems that are left for the reader to prove would benefit from a simple spoiler in the spirit of those on math.se

For example, a good use of the spoiler's functionality can be found [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529955/c-0-the-space-of-sequences-converging-0-is-complete-with-dual-ell1-math/1529967#1529967)

So, my question is whether or not it is possible to implement this functionality in pdf documents.

Something like:

**Theorem 4.5:** There are infinitely many primes.

> ! Suppose there were finitely many primes. Multiply them together and add 1. What can you say about this new number?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Note that spoilers don't work here once the question is posted even though they work when you are editing it.

Comment: Related or possibly duplicate: [pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/)

Comment: @MikeRenfro That code doesn't seem to render for me in Sublime Text 3

Comment: @MikeRenfro Or at all when using overleaf

Comment: A lot of this type of thing is specific to Adobe Reader. Try that as well?

Comment: @MikeRenfro I should also say that I'm looking for something to be **inserted** into an already existing document, rather than having to use this particular document class

Comment: Just looked at the solution in a bit more detail. I don't think the document class (scrbook or other) is relevant, since all the interesting stuff is in the preamble. Some level of LaTeX 3 support may be required, but shouldn't be a problem with common recent distributions. If you want to manipulate an existing PDF, that's a different problem.