# Using tooltip with paracol

Tags: xetex, paracol

I am trying to typeset a document using XeLaTeX that has parallel columns (using `paracol`). In the document, I want to have tooltips for notes. I am using the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005/97086. The tooltips show up on the left side, but they don't show up on the other side. Is it possible to have the tooltips show up on both sides?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\setCJKmainfont{MOESongUN}
\setCJKmonofont{TW-Sung-Ext-B}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\newcommand{\ver}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1 }\nolinebreak}
\newcommand{\paral}[2]{
\begin{column*}
#1
\end{column*}
\begin{column}
#2
\end{column}}

\usepackage{xparse,pdfbase,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnn{1}{1}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{ssO{black}mO{yellow!20}m}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{%
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border [0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        /AA<<%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
          /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
        >>%
      }{
        /AA<<%
          /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
            var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
            \IfBooleanF{#1}{%
              if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                var click\thetcnt=false;%
                var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
              }%
            }%
            if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
              fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
            }%
           this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
            if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
            if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
            this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
          /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
          /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
            var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
            try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
            fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
          )>>%
      /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
    >>%
  }
}%
  }{{\color{#3}#4}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{\fcolorbox{black}{#5}{#6}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \tpPdfXform{\tiptext}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#4}+\tdp}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
      /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
      /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
      /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        /Ff 65537/OC \tpTipOcg%
      }{%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
              >>%
            >>%
          }%
        }%
        \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
      }}%
      \stepcounter{tcnt}%
    }}
    \makeatother
    \newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
    \newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
    \newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
          [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\nt}[1]{\mbox{-{}-#1}}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\tooltip*{$^\star$}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4}
\footnotelayout{m}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\paral{\ver{20}上帝講：「水著生湠濟濟有活命的動物；鳥\note{「鳥」，本文，「有翼的類」。}飛佇地的頂面，天裡的穹蒼\note{「穹蒼」，本文，「穹蒼的面」。}。」}{\ver{20}Siōng-tè kóng: ``Tsuí tio̍h senn-thuànn tsē-tsē ū ua̍h-miā ê tōng-bu̍t; tsiáu\note{\textit{Tsiáu}, pún-bûn, \textit{ū si̍t ê luī}.} pue tī tē ê tíng-bīn, thinn\nt{lí} ê kiong-tshong\note{\textit{Kiong-tshong}, pún-bûn, \textit{kiong-tshong ê bīn}.}.''}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Interestingly, if I use `\tooltip` instead of `\tooltip*`, hovering over the tooltips on the right side make the corresponding tooltips on the left side show up.