# Multiple lines and enumeration needed in Tooltip tool

Tags: beamer, fancytooltips, tooltips

I got to know the Tooltip tool whos macros is given [pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-infrom-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip/120005#120005). When I am trying to include ``\\", \begin{enumeration} or \begin{itemize}, this tooltip is failing. In fact, no matter how long I type, the whole text is coming into one line. Kindly, suggest me a way so that the text gets justified in multiple lines without crossing pdf page and I can also use \begin{enumeration} and \begin{itemize} commands in \toooltip

Comment: Put multiple lines stuff in a `\parbox`, as suggested in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that comment. I have used it and it worked but inserting an image inside of it is still not working properly. Is it feasible using \parbox?

Comment: E. g.: `\parbox{0.6\linewidth}{\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}}`