# Tooltip not generating desired output

Tags: beamer, fancytooltips, tooltips

I got to know the Tooltip tool whos macros is given here [pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-infrom-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip/120005#120005). It was very helpful and I have used it several times but since last few days, I am not getting the desired output. Precisely, suppose that I am running beamer file having 10 slides and using tooltip on 2nd, 3rd and 8th slide. When I am checking the output in pdf, tooltip is appearing only on 8th slide but not on 2nd and 3rd slides. This error is coming with my old pdf files as well (these files were running perfectly before 7 to 8 months from now with same reader). Kindly help me out.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you without any code provided. Please try to come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You can make a copy of your non-working file and comment out parts where you think the problem lies. If the rest is working, you know that the error really is in this part you just commented out. This way, you should be able to arrow down the problem step by step.